# Statistics of System usage time (time of day, day of week)

Tags: linux, command, statistics

I once found a tool that printed a huge amount of statistics about the time of day and day of week of computer usage when invoked. Unfortunately I don't remember the name neither did Google reveal it again for me.

Can anyone help finding it?

It was a console tool, possibly Python and rendering even fancy Unicode and color output for the statistics. Iirc it used something like syslog to roughly estimating if the computer was running at a given hour.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about `sysstat`:
[sysstat](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this is not the tool I am looking for. It was not telling any performance details, it just showed if the device was running or not.